# creating user profile force user to change password on first login in oracle

Tags: oracle

could any one help me how to write sql command to create a  profile force user to change password on first login.

I know it is possible when we want to create user but I want to do it when I am creating profile.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I don't believe you can do this with a profile. You can set other limits like password life time, grace time, lock time, reuse time, etc. but neither the default profile nor the documentation suggest a limit for password expire time for a profile. In order to expire a user I've always used:

```
alter user scott password expire;
```

If you want to do this automatically, I suggest writing a script or stored procedure.

Worst case scenario, you could probably accomplish this using a logon trigger, but be careful doing it. The cleanest way is a script or stored proc to add users anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER USER username PASSWORD EXPIRE;`

From documentation :

> If you cause a database user's password to expire with PASSWORD
>   EXPIRE, then the user (or the DBA) must change the password before
>   attempting to log in to the database following the expiration.
>   However, tools such as SQL*Plus allow the user to change the password
>   on the first attempted login following the expiration.

Link to documentation about `ALTER USER` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4003.htm